# Discreteness of the higher inductive-inductive Cauchy real numbers in real cohesive homotopy type theory

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology, constructive-mathematics, homotopy-type-theory

We work in cohesive homotopy type theory with propositional resizing, so that there is only one type of Dedekind real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ up to equivalence, and Mike Shulman's axiom $\mathbb{R}\flat$, which states that the only (continuous) functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to every discrete cohesive type $A$ are the constant functions to $A$. We do not assume any classical axioms such as excluded middle or the axiom of choice, or weakened versions thereof such as countable choice or the limited principle of omniscience, so we are working entirely in constructive mathematics.

The Cauchy real numbers $\mathbb{R}_C$ are defined in the footnote on page 46 of Mike Shulman's [Brouwer's fixed-point theorem in real-cohesive homotopy type theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.07584) as "a quotient of the set of Cauchy sequences or approximations", and in theorem 8.26 Mike Shulman proves that $\mathbb{R}_C$ is discrete as a cohesive type.

However, there is another definition of the real numbers as a higher inductive-inductive type given in section 11.3 of the Univalent Foundations Project's [Homotopy Type Theory: Univalent Foundations of Mathematics](https://hott.github.io/book/hott-online-1351-g99f4de9.pdf), as the free sequential Cauchy completion of the rational numbers, which shall be written as $\mathbb{R}_H$ in this question. Without weak countable choice, $\mathbb{R}_H$ is not provable to be equivalent to $\mathbb{R}_C$. Is $\mathbb{R}_H$ also discrete as a cohesive type?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, although if I had to guess I would guess that the answer is yes.  But I wanted to point out that I did prove in the BFP paper (Corollary 8.27) that $\mathbb{R}_H = \mathbb{R}_C$ assuming only the "punctual cohesion" axiom C1 and the *sharp* axiom of choice, which are consistent with very constructive behavior in the cohesive world.  In particular, these axioms do not imply $\mathbb{R}_C = \mathbb{R}_D$, and hence do not imply ordinary countable choice or excluded middle.  I don't know whether they imply WCC, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: Cohesion where the *discrete* world, not just the cohesive world, is constructive, is an interesting thing to think about.  But I think it's poorly understood, and is likely to exhibit odd behavior (compared to cohesion where the discrete world is classical), because the "intrinsically topological" behavior of constructive objects is somehow "split" between that which appears already in the discrete world and that which is "added" in the cohesive world.